# Coordinate transformation from a curve line to a straight line

Tags: math, coordinate-transformation

Suppose I have a curve in xy coordinate system and I know the function of the curve is y=x^2. How could I map this curve to a new uv coordinate system and it should be a straight line (y=c1).

I searched that I could use Jacobian determinant to do this job but I don't know how to find the components of the transformation. (x(u,v),y(u,v))

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ would probably be the best place for this question. Unless you already tried coding this solution and could provide what you have done so far.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and probably belongs on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

```
u=x, v=y-x²
```

does the job. Is there an extended question behind?

Comment: How do you figure it out? What if it's a more complex function like polynomial with power 6 ? What I did is to calculate the length of the curve and map it to the new coordinate system. Am I right?